# Bi-weekly payments with dividends or other investments

Tags: dividends, cash-flow, passive-income

I am aware that dividends pay out 4 times a year. I would like to start earning passive income using dividends.

My question is Is there any way to buy different stocks that payout at different times of the year and create a way where I would get paid every two weeks of the year due to the differences in when each stock pays out their dividends.

For example say I buy stock **X** that might pay out Jan 1st, April 1st, August 1st and Dec 1st. Then I buy another stock **Y** that pays out Feb 1st, May 1st,
July 1st and Nov 1st. Then I would expect dividend payouts for my two stocks in Jan, Feb, April,May,July,August,Nov, and Dec.

Say I buy 5 more stocks that pay out at different times of the year then I determine when they payout their dividend and structure it to where I would receive payments in a bi weekly fashion.

Is This possible to do? If it is not then what other investment products are available to achieve passive income in a bi weekly fashion or even monthly fashion.

Comment: Dividends are so small, unless you are talking million$ in stocks it just doesn't matter and isn't worth bothering with.

Comment: Even if all dividends were paid quarterly, just configure your brokerage account to make bi-weekly transfers to your checking account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numerous stocks go ex-dividend every day of the week so you can craft any pay out schedule that amuses you.  You can see past as well as future ex dates here:

https://www.nasdaq.com/dividend-stocks/dividend-calendar.aspx

I wouldn't create an investment portfolio based solely on  dividend dates, particularly since a dividend is merely a return of your own money from your brokerage account. Now if you invested in financially healthy companies that were growing and also pay a dividend, that's a different story.